# How to use protocol and delegate in my class?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, delegates, protocols

I am using two view Controllers i.e. StateListVC and PlayVC. In StateListVC, I am using container view with 3 VCs. After tapping on 3rd View Controller, I am going to PlayVC with delegate method. I don't know how to do that. Please help me to resolve this issue.

StateListVC

```
class StateListVC: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        if isMoveToAnotherVC
        {
            let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "PlaceVC") as! PlaceVC
            vc.delegate = self
        }

    }
}

extension StateListVC: MoveToAnotherVC {
    func moving(string: String) {
        print(string)
    }
}
```

ThirdVC

```
protocol MoveToAnotherVC {
    func moving(string: String)
}

class PlaceVC: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableViewPlace: UITableView!
    var delegate: MoveToAnotherVC? = nil

    var arrPlace = ["Place1", "Place2"]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

extension PlaceVC: UITableViewDataSource {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return arrPlace.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel?.text = arrPlace[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }
}

extension PlaceVC: UITableViewDelegate {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)
    {
        isMoveToAnotherVC = true

        print(delegate)
        guard let delegate = self.delegate else{
            print("Delegate not set")
            return
        }

        delegate.moving(string: "test")
    }
}
```

Comment: who is the rootViewController  `StateListVC ` or ` PlaceVC` , then Are you need to press on third Controller in Containerview to open PlaceCV or what?

Answer (score 0):

This is hooked up fine:

```
protocol MoveToAnotherVC: AnyObject {
    func moving(string: String)
}

class StateListVC: UIViewController, MoveToAnotherVC {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "PlaceVC") as! PlaceVC
        vc.delegate = self
    }

    func moving(string: String) {
        print(string)
    }

}

class PlaceVC: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableViewPlace: UITableView!
    weak var delegate: MoveToAnotherVC?
    var arrPlace = ["Place1", "Place2"]

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return arrPlace.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel?.text = arrPlace[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        delegate?.moving(string: "test")
    }

}
```

I made the protocol a class protocol, moved the view controller instantiation into `viewDidLoad`, removed some (what I consider) extraneous unwrapping, and stripped your protocol/delegate pattern down to the basics. This works. I would plug this into your project and add what you need piece by piece until it breaks because your problem is outside of this. I suspect it may have to do with something you didn't include in your question but this answers your question about how to set up a protocol/delegate pattern.